# Customize JPA field name mapping using EclipseLink

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I need to map camel-case names to underscore-separated names in my current project, which uses EclipseLink, due to historical reasons. I know we can customize name mapping individually in JPA, but we have a long list of camel-case names to change, so we want to avoid that kind of boilerplate codes if all possible.

What I want to achieve is as follows. Suppose we have an entity class as below:

```
@Entity
public class FooBar {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date dateCreated;
}
```

I want this class maps to a table with name "foo_bar" and columns "id" and "date_created". Note that all names in database are in lower case.

I googled around, and found a solution for changing table names. However, I can't figure out how to change field names in an entity class.

Below is my name-mapping customizer, where the method `updateFieldNameMappings()` is not mapping `fieldName` to `field_name`, which is what I want to achieve. The problem boils down to how to get the field name as in the class definition. So, how do I do that in EclipseLink?

```
public class JpaNameMappingCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize( Session session ) throws Exception {
        Map<Class, ClassDescriptor> descs = session.getDescriptors();
        Collection<ClassDescriptor> descriptors = descs.values();

        // This code assumes single table per descriptor!
        for (ClassDescriptor desc : descriptors) {
            updateTableNameMapping( desc );
            updateFieldNameMapping( desc );
        }
    }

    private void updateTableNameMapping ( ClassDescriptor desc ) {
        Class clazz = desc.getJavaClass();
        String tableName = camelCaseToUnderscore( clazz.getSimpleName() );
        desc.setTableName( tableName );
    }

    private void updateFieldNameMapping ( ClassDescriptor desc ) {
        // build name maps
        Field[] fields = desc.getJavaClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String tableName = desc.getTableName();
        Map<String,String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
        String prefix = tableName + ".";
        for( Field field : fields ) {
            String name = field.getName();
            String key = prefix + name.toUpperCase();
            String value = prefix + camelCaseToUnderscore( name );
            nameMap.put( key, value );
        }

        for (DatabaseMapping mapping : desc.getMappings()) {
            if (mapping.isDirectToFieldMapping()) {
                DirectToFieldMapping directMapping = (DirectToFieldMapping) mapping;
                String oldFieldName = directMapping.getFieldName(); // format: table_name.FIELD
                directMapping.setFieldName( nameMap.get( oldFieldName ) );
            }
        }
    }

    private String camelCaseToUnderscore( String camelCase ) {
        return camelCase.trim().replaceAll("(?<!^)[A-Z](?!$)", "_$0").toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**edit 11/10/13**
I did some hacking and changed the customizer. The `updateFieldNameMapping()` still doesn't do the trick. It seems to me that this statement `directMapping.setFieldName( nameMap.get( oldFieldName ) )` inside the method doesn't actually change the field name mapping, which really confuses me.

**edit 11/11/13**
I forgot to make it clear that I had the `eclipselink.session.customizer` enabled in the `persistence.xml`. Namely, I have a line like below in the `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="pkg.JpaNameMappingCustomizer"/>
```

Comment: When you say it is not giving what you want, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JamesB: Thanks for the question. I updated my post. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: setFieldName should create a DatabaseField object from the passed in string, so check that getFieldName returns what you expect after the call.  Can you see when your customizer is getting called?  As it is only operating on direct to field mappings (basic JPA mappings) any other fields defined in other mappings will be excluded.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the comment. Per your suggestion, I double checked the field name after calling the `setFieldName()`. It shows the field name I wanted, but Eclipselink somehow still uses the old field for mapping. For example, suppose I get `table_name.foo_bar` from `getFieldName()` after calling `setFieldName()`. However, I still get an error like `There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [table_name.FOOBAR]`.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226244/jpa-set-column-name-for-joincolumnname-at-runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
directMapping.setFieldName(nameMap.get(oldFieldName ));
```

try:

```
directMapping.getField().resetQualifiedName(nameMap.get(oldFieldName));
```

This does the trick for me under EclipseLink 2.5.0

Comment: Could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226244/jpa-set-column-name-for-joincolumnname-at-runtime

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use my session customizer. It converts table names, and field names to Camel case. It supports **inheritance and embeded** entities.
I tested for 2 years, and I got no issues or side effects. Enjoy it!

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
import org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.IndexDefinition;

public class CamelNamingStrategy implements SessionCustomizer {
    public static String unqualify(final String qualifiedName) {
        int loc = qualifiedName.lastIndexOf(".");
        return loc < 0 ? qualifiedName : qualifiedName.substring(qualifiedName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(final Session session) throws SQLException {
        for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : session.getDescriptors().values()) {
            if (!descriptor.getTables().isEmpty()) {
                // Take table name from @Table if exists
                String tableName = null;
                if (descriptor.getAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(descriptor.getTableName())) {
                    tableName = unqualify(descriptor.getJavaClassName());
                } else {
                    tableName = descriptor.getTableName();
                }
                tableName = camelCaseToUnderscore(tableName);
                descriptor.setTableName(tableName);
                for (IndexDefinition index : descriptor.getTables().get(0).getIndexes()) {
                    index.setTargetTable(tableName);
                }
                Vector<DatabaseMapping> mappings = descriptor.getMappings();
                camelCaseToUnderscore(mappings);
            } else if (descriptor.isAggregateDescriptor() || descriptor.isChildDescriptor()) {
                camelCaseToUnderscore(descriptor.getMappings());
            }
        }
    }

    private void camelCaseToUnderscore(Vector<DatabaseMapping> mappings) {
        for (DatabaseMapping mapping : mappings) {
            DatabaseField field = mapping.getField();
            if (mapping.isDirectToFieldMapping() && !mapping.isPrimaryKeyMapping()) {
                String attributeName = mapping.getAttributeName();
                String underScoredFieldName = camelCaseToUnderscore(attributeName);
                field.setName(underScoredFieldName);
            }
        }
    }

    private String camelCaseToUnderscore(final String name) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(name.replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i))
                    && Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226244/jpa-set-column-name-for-joincolumnname-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed adding following line in your `persistence.xml` to say `EclipseLink` to use your own `SessionCustomizer`

```
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="your.company.package.name.JpaNameMappingCustomizer"/>
```

Refer

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/dbws/creating_dbws_services002.htm

http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_session_customizer.htm#CHDFBIEI

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I do have that line in my persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to distinguish between non-annotated elements and annotated elements using @Column annotations, then I found a very beautiful example doing this:

```
public class CamelCaseSessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(Session session) throws SQLException {
    for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : session.getDescriptors().values()) {
        // Only change the table name for non-embedable entities with no
        // @Table already
        if (!descriptor.getTables().isEmpty() && descriptor.getAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(descriptor.getTableName())) {
            String tableName = addUnderscores(descriptor.getTableName());
            descriptor.setTableName(tableName);
            for (IndexDefinition index : descriptor.getTables().get(0).getIndexes()) {
                index.setTargetTable(tableName);
            }
        }
        for (DatabaseMapping mapping : descriptor.getMappings()) {
            // Only change the column name for non-embedable entities with
            // no @Column already

            if (mapping instanceof AggregateObjectMapping) {
                for (Association association : ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getAggregateToSourceFieldAssociations()) {
                    DatabaseField field = (DatabaseField) association.getValue();
                    field.setName(addUnderscores(field.getName()));

                    for (DatabaseMapping attrMapping : session.getDescriptor(((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getReferenceClass()).getMappings()) {
                        if (attrMapping.getAttributeName().equalsIgnoreCase((String) association.getKey())) {
                            ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).addFieldTranslation(field, addUnderscores(attrMapping.getAttributeName()));
                            ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getAggregateToSourceFields().remove(association.getKey());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (mapping instanceof ObjectReferenceMapping) {
                for (DatabaseField foreignKey : ((ObjectReferenceMapping) mapping).getForeignKeyFields()) {
                    foreignKey.setName(addUnderscores(foreignKey.getName()));
                }
            } else if (mapping instanceof DirectMapMapping) {
                for (DatabaseField referenceKey : ((DirectMapMapping) mapping).getReferenceKeyFields()) {
                    referenceKey.setName(addUnderscores(referenceKey.getName()));
                }
                for (DatabaseField sourceKey : ((DirectMapMapping) mapping).getSourceKeyFields()) {
                    sourceKey.setName(addUnderscores(sourceKey.getName()));
                }
            } else {
                DatabaseField field = mapping.getField();
                if (field != null && !mapping.getAttributeName().isEmpty() && field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(mapping.getAttributeName())) {
                    field.setName(addUnderscores(mapping.getAttributeName()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static String addUnderscores(String name) {
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("begintime")) {
        System.err.println();
    }
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(name.replace('.', '_'));
    for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i)) && Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))) {
            buf.insert(i++, '_');
        }
    }
    return buf.toString().toLowerCase();
}

}
```

From https://gist.github.com/ganeshs/c0deb77ffae33dee4555