# EclipseLink set column name for @JoinColumn(name = "") at runtime

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I need to change column names for all fields at runtime. I use eclipselink and do it via `SessionCustomizer`.

However, I can change column names for `usual` columns, those which are not in any relations.

Now I have a field in @ManyToOne relation and defines its column using @JoinColumn(name = "thisColumnToChage"). How to do it? This is my code:

```
private void setNameMaping(ClassDescriptor desc){
  desc.setTableName(NEW TABLE NAME);
 //setting columns for fields
  for (DatabaseMapping mapping : desc.getMappings()) {
    if (mapping.isDirectToFieldMapping()) {
         directMapping.getField().resetQualifiedName(NEW COLUM NAME);
    }else if (mapping.isManyToOneMapping()){
        ManyToOneMapping manyToOneMapping=(ManyToOneMapping)mapping;
         WHAT IS HERE?
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: I mean are you currently getting any errors?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen For simple fields everything works ok. However, I don't know how to implement for ManyToOne fileds.

Comment: Check out the javadocs for https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/OneToOneMapping.html and you will want to look at the EclipseLink source for the addForeignKeyFieldName and addForeignKeyField methods.  in a 1:1 that owns the FK, you will need to replace the sourceForeignKeyField with your new one in the getForeignKeyFields list as well as the getSourceToTargetKeyFields and getTargetToSourceKeyFields maps