# Where in the eclipselink api is the field information of a list of an @embeddable class encoded?

Tags: mysql, eclipselink

I am trying to write a SessionCustomizer that will translate camelCase field names to under_score. I have found [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896352/customize-jpa-field-name-mapping-using-eclipselink/19902591#19902591) that basically follow the following strategy: loop over the `ClassDescriptor` objects in `Session.getDescriptors().values()`, and then loop over the `DatabaseMapping` objects in `ClassDescriptor.getMappings()`.

The problem is that this only reaches direct attributes of a class, it does nothing to the attributes of an `@embeddable` class, a list of which is an attribute of the main class through `@ElementCollection` (and ends up in a separate table).

I believe that such an attribute is encoded as an [`AggregateCollectionMapping`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/AggregateCollectionMapping.html) (a subsubsubclass of `DatabaseMapping`), but I cannot find the list of `DatabaseMapping` objects that this should in turn have, and which I would like to loop over again.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses `AggregateCollectionMapping` and `AggregateObjectMapping` for embedded attribute mappings.

Class descriptor of embedded attribute can be found at `rootEntityClassDescriptor#mappings#embeddedMapping#referenceDescriptor`. Reference descriptor contains attribute mappings of embedded entity.

Comment: Thank you for registering to answer my question! I now realise my question is partially based on a misunderstanding. I think I will have to ask a new question.